# Cannot read property 'date' of undefined React material design

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-design, material-ui

I am using storybook reactJs and material-ui for an app. I am trying to build datepicker from [Material-ui component](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/demo/datepicker) and below is my code so far

```
import React, { Fragment, PureComponent } from 'react';
import  {DatePicker}  from 'material-ui-pickers';

class DatePickers extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    selectedDate: new Date(),
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
  const  { selectedDate } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          label="Basic example"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          animateYearScrolling={false}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DatePickers;
```

when i open my storybook it shows the below error
Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
>       at DatePickerWrapper.PickerBase._this.getValidDateOrCurrent (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:52555:24)
>       at DatePickerWrapper.PickerBase (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:52559:19)

Does anyone know. what's going on here?

Comment: Did you tried with moving your state assignment in constructor() ?

Comment: Have you tried using `const  selectedDate = this.state.selectedDate;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1r9x22pk5q) containing your code for the `DatePicker` component.

The error might be in the following - did you wrap your component in `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` with the required `utils` prop provided?

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
  <DatePicker />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: worked . thanks . but do you know why is there a scrollbar

Comment: and arrows missing

Comment: Not sure what scrollbar are you talking about.. And the arrows missing because you didn't import Material UI icons. Please refer to [this page](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/installation) - at the very bottom there is a `Font Icons` section. You need to include the icons. Updated sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/1r9x22pk5q

Answer (score 0):

make sure to npm install date-fns, react, react-dom, @mui/lab, and @mui/material